# Split string into array regex php

Tags: php, arrays, regex

I need to split the string bellow into array keys like in this format:

string = `"(731) some text here with number 2 (220) some 54 number other text here"` convert into:

```
array( 
  '731' => 'some text here with number 2', 
  '220' => 'some 54 number other text here' 
);
```

I have tried:

```
preg_split( '/\([0-9]{3}\)/', $string );
```

and got:

```
array ( 
  0 => 'some text here', 
  1 => 'some other text here' 
);
```

Comment: I think, you should represent the data in question in little better format. It will be easier for community to read it and reply.

Comment: The requirements are too vague. Could you at least provide the expected output for the provided input string?

Comment: And maybe what you tried yourself until now?

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: I'm guessing you want the numbers in the string to be the keys in your array, correct?

Comment: @Henders yep correct :) but only the ones in parentheses () and when parentheses contains 3 numbers.

Comment: you can first split the whole string by  regex:   /\s(?=\(\d+\))/   and than again split each with following regex : /\((\d+(?=\)))\)\s(.*)/  and than get group 1st as key and 2nd as value. I don't know php if you need I can provide with javascript or java

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Code**

```php
$string = "(731) some text here with number 2 (220) some 54 number other text here";

preg_match_all("/\((\d{3})\) *([^( ]*(?> +[^( ]+)*)/", $string, $matches);
$result = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);

var_dump($result);
```

**Output**

```
array(2) {
  [731]=>
  string(28) "some text here with number 2"
  [220]=>
  string(30) "some 54 number other text here"
}
```

<kbd>[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/xUVtiY)</kbd>

---

**Description**

The regex uses

- `\((\d{3})\)` to match 3 digits in parentheses and captures it (group 1)
- `\ *` to match the spaces in between keys and values
- `([^( ]*(?> +[^( ]+)*)` to match everything except a `(` and captures it (group 2)
  This subpattern matches exactly the same as `[^(]*(?<! )` but more efficiently, based on the [*unrolling-the-loop* technique](http://www.softec.lu/site/RegularExpressions/UnrollingTheLoop).

  *Notice though that I am interpreting a value field cannot have a `(` within. If that is not the case, do tell and I will modify it accordingly.

After that, we have `$matches[1]` with keys and `$matches[2]` with values. Using [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) we generate the desired array.

Comment: Up-voted only for the use of `array_combine()`. Two issues with your RegEx: 1- Unnecessary possessive quantifiers. 2- Ignoring parenthesis from being within strings (which may be there).

Comment: Why should you think there could be a failure case for `\s*+` and `[^( ]*+`?

Comment: Hah! Right! No idea what I was thinking. Thanks for the heads-up

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$string = "(731) some text here with number 2 (220) some 54 number other text here";
$a = preg_split('/\s(?=\()/', $string);//split by spaces preceding the left bracket
$res = array();
foreach($a as $v){
    $r = preg_split('/(?<=\))\s/', $v);//split by spaces following the right bracket
    if(isset($r[0]) && isset($r[1])){
        $res[trim($r[0],'() ')] = trim($r[1]);//trim brackets and spaces
    }
}
print_r($res);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [731] => some text here with number 2
    [220] => some 54 number other text here
)
```

[DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4f66ae492e1a9a905dfb41ba2e2844c8c0f4acae)

If you want to limit it only to those numbers in brackets that have 3 digits, just modify the lookarounds:

```
$a = preg_split('/\s(?=\([0-9]{3}\))/', $string);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this one,

```
<?php
$str="(731) some text here (220) some other text here";
echo $str .'<br>';
$arr1=explode('(', $str);
$size_arr=count($arr1);
$final_arr=array();
for($i=1;$i<$size_arr; $i++){
    $arr2=explode(')', $arr1[$i]);
    $final_arr[$arr2[0]]=trim($arr2[1]);
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($final_arr);
?>
```

Use this link to test the code, [Click Here.](http://phptester.net/)

I try to use the simple syntax. Hope everybody can understand.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can add `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` flag to `preg_split`. From preg_split man page (http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)

> PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE
>
> If this flag is set, parenthesized expression in the delimiter pattern will be captured and returned as well.

So if you change your code to:

```
$results = preg_split('/\(([0-9]+)\)/s', $data,null,PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

You will obtain an array similar to:

```
Array
(
    [0] => KS/M/ 2013/1238 
    [1] => 220
    [2] =>  23/12/2013 
    [3] => 300
    [4] => 

    [5] => 731
    [6] =>  VALDETE BUZA ADEM JASHARI- PRIZREN, KS 
    [7] => 526
    [8] => 

    [9] => 591
    [10] => 

    [11] => 740
    [12] => 


    [13] => 540
    [14] =>  DEINA 
    [15] => 546
    [16] => 


    [17] => 511
    [18] =>  3 Preparatet për zbardhim dhe substancat tjera për larje rrobash; preparatet për pastrim, shkëlqim, fërkim dhe gërryerje; sapunët; parfumet, vajrat esencialë, preparatet kozmetike, losionet për flokë, pasta për dhembe
14 Metalet e cmueshme dhe aliazhet e tyre; mallrat në metale të cmueshme ose të veshura me to, që nuk janë përfshire në klasat tjera; xhevahirët, gurët e cmueshëm; instrumentet horologjike dhe kronometrike (për matjen dhe regjistrimin e kohës)
25 Rrobat, këpucët, kapelat
35 Reklamim, menaxhim biznesi; administrim biznesi; funksione zyre
)
```

What you should do is to loop over the array ignoring first element in that case:

```
$myArray = array();
$myKey = '';
foreach ($results as $k => $v) {
  if ( ($k > 0) && ($myKey == '')) {
    $myKey = $v;
  } else if ($k > 0) {
    $myArray[$myKey] = $v; 
    $myKey = '';
  }
}
```

**EDIT:** This answer is for:

```
$data ='KS/M/ 2013/1238 (220) 23/12/2013 (300)
(731) VALDETE BUZA ADEM JASHARI- PRIZREN, KS (526)
(591)
(740)

(540) DEINA (546)

(511) 3 Preparatet për zbardhim dhe substancat tjera për larje rrobash; preparatet për pastrim, shkëlqim, fërkim dhe gërryerje; sapunët; parfumet, vajrat esencialë, preparatet kozmetike, losionet për flokë, pasta për dhembe
14 Metalet e cmueshme dhe aliazhet e tyre; mallrat në metale të cmueshme ose të veshura me to, që nuk janë përfshire në klasat tjera; xhevahirët, gurët e cmueshëm; instrumentet horologjike dhe kronometrike (për matjen dhe regjistrimin e kohës)
25 Rrobat, këpucët, kapelat
35 Reklamim, menaxhim biznesi; administrim biznesi; funksione zyre';
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that defining the keys is not possible, as the regex will add matches coninuously.
I would define 2 regex,
one for the keys:

```
preg_match_all("/(\()([0-9]*)(\))\s/", $input_lines, $output_array);
```

you will find your keys in $output_array[2].
And one for the texts (that looks quite the same):

```
preg_split("/(\()([0-9]*)(\))\s/", $input_line);
```

After that, you can build your custom array iterating over both.
Make sure to trim the strings in the second array when inserting.

Answer (score 1):

Using `preg_replace_callback()` you can quickly achieve what you desire (when only parentheses contain 3 digits):

```
$string = "(731) some text here with number 2 (220) some 54 number other text here";
$array = array();
preg_replace_callback('~(\((\d{3})\))(.*?)(?=(?1)|\Z)~s', function($match) use (&$array) {
    $array[$match[2]] = trim($match[3]);
}, $string);
var_dump($array);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [731]=>
  string(28) "some text here with number 2"
  [220]=>
  string(30) "some 54 number other text here"
}
```